# Firebase password auth not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build a login using the firebase email/password auth. I have set up my project and keys and everything works on the android side. I am trying to build the web side of it and can't seem to get the login to work.

Here is my javascript:

```
(function(){

// Initialize Firebase
  const config = {
    apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
    authDomain: "MY_AUTH_DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "MY_DATABASE_URL",
    storageBucket: "MY_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Get elements
const loginEmail = document.getElementById('loginEmail');
const loginPassword = document.getElementById('loginPassword');
const loginButton = document.getElementById("loginButton");

// Add login event
loginButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Get email and password
    const email = loginEmail.value;
    const pass = loginPassword.value;
    var auth = firebase.auth();

    // Sign in
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log("Error code: " + errorCode);
        console.log("Error message: " + errorMessage);
    });
});


}());
```

Here are the errors I keep getting:

```
Error code: auth/internal-error
Error message: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"keyExpired","message":"Bad Request"}],"code":400,"message":"Bad Request"}}
```

Comment: are you sure your config values are up to date? everything else looks correct

Comment: Yes. I've copied them straight from the firebase console. I created another project an it works. I just can't get it to work with my current project.

Comment: ok, well "usageLimits" sounds like too many connections are being made, do you know if a large number of users are connecting to your db?

Comment: That's what I first thought but looking in the console, I have 0 connections.

Comment: There is probably some problem with your api key. Maybe you set some restrictions on it. Did you manually configure it? It is usually automatically created for you when you start a new firebase project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced same error and it is because I generated a new key from console.developers.google.com and still using the old Auto Generated API Keys (which was deleted). Got this resolved, when I re downloaded a new config file or replacing the old api key to the newly created/auto created key.